# Why is `Hello`, `Thanks` etc. are not allowed?

Tags: discussion

Every time I open a question, I open the message with "Hello", and end with "Thanks".

Too many times my messages get edited, and these lines are removed.

I've always wanted to know: why these words are not allowed?

Comment: its a question not a letter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We attempt to maintain a high signal to noise ratio. Here signal is things that are helpful and noise is things that aren't. This allows for future users to be able to get straight to the information they need rather than wading trough a sea of (if we're honest) irrelevant information.

Greetings neither make questions clearer nor answer questions so are noise

Comment: `Greetings neither make questions clearer nor answer questions, so are noise.` **Yes**!

Comment: With the greatest of respect, is a word or two very much noise?  A little politesse sometimes makes the world turn more smoothly.  I would agree that you don't want florid salutations.   I suppose the question then becomes where to draw the line, and "none" is at least unambiguous.

Comment: @RFlack Saying please and thank you is too easy a form of politeness. I prefer my politeness in the form of well written questions